# Crasher in a custom view as UINavigationControllers navigationItem.titleView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I have an `UIViewController` with several subviews in its view property (`UISearchbar` and several `UIButton`s). The `UIButton`s hooked up to typical `IBAction`s like `-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender` for the `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` state - it doesn't matter if I do it in IB or programmatically.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    MUZTitleViewController *title = [[MUZTitleViewController alloc] 
                                     initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = title.view;
}
```

In my project there's also an `UINavigationController`. When I set the `navigationItem.titleView` of the `UINavigationBar` to the view of my `UIViewController`s view I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception, as soon as I tap one of the button. I don't know why this is.

I uploaded a small sample project to illustrate my problem: [Test010.xcodeproj](http://cl.ly/A1xU) (it's ARC enabled)

More and more I come to the conclusion that it's not a good idea to use the `UIViewController`s view and assign it to the `titleView` but I don't see any alternative here.

**Edit:** Sorry, the sample project commented out the call which causes the exception. I reuploaded the linked project file.

**Edit^2:** As PengOne pointed out I've skipped the exact error message I got:

```
2011-09-10 23:09:50.621 Test010[78639:f803] -[CALayer buttonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9254ae0
2011-09-10 23:09:50.623 Test010[78639:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CALayer buttonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9254ae0'
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting NSZombieEnabled to YES? If I do this, the console shows the following output:

```
2011-09-10 22:56:23.329 Test010[6481:ef03] *** -[MUZTitleViewController
performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated 
instance 0x7a7ff70
```

As the project is ARC enabled, the controller seems to get deallocated some time after this line:

```
MUZTitleViewController *title = [[MUZTitleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

I am not sure what the best solution is, but a property definitely helps to prevent the exception like so:

```
// MUZDetailViewController.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) MUZTitleViewController *title;

// MUZDetailViewController.m
@synthesize title;

self.title = [[MUZTitleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.navigationItem.titleView = title.view;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. In fact the problem was that ARC deallocated my VC before its got called from the buttons UIControlEvent. Making it a property of the instancing VC ensures that ARC don't prematurely deallocate it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you were having with ARC can also be resolved by setting the initial view controller of your application as your main window's `rootViewController` property instead of using `addSubview`.

Doing this avoids the need to add each custom view controller as a property.