# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error UIButton's IBAction with ARC

Tags: iphone, uibutton, exc-bad-access

I am developing an Iphone Application with Xcode 4.3.2 for iOS 4.1

I had added a UIButton in UIView from IB and connect it with an IBAction.
But when i touched down the button i got EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

I enabled ARC when i was creating the project.

After this error and googling i learnt that bad memory management cause this error; but i couldn't determine what does cause this problem. 
How can i find the problem?

.h file contains

```
-(IBAction)openTwitterSignInViewController:(id)sender;
```

.m file contains

```
- (void)openTwitterSignInViewController:(id)sender{
    UIViewController *secondViewController = [[TwitterSignInViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TwitterSignInViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES]; 
}
```

Also `UIButton` and `openTwitterSignInViewController` connected via IB.

There is no console output, i don't know why. So i am adding a screenshot.
[image]

LoginViewController.m

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "Helper.h"
#import "TwitterSignInViewController.h"

@interface LoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginViewController
@synthesize topBarText, userNameText, passwordText, passwordReminderButton, loginButton;
@synthesize signInTwitterButton, registerButton;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 20)];

    userNameText.leftView = paddingView;
    userNameText.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

    passwordText.leftView = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:
                             [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: paddingView]];
    passwordText.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

    topBarText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Neo Sans Pro" size:14 ];
    userNameText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Neo Sans Pro" size:14];

    passwordText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Neo Sans Pro" size:14];
    passwordReminderButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Neo Sans Pro" size:14];
    loginButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Neo Sans Pro" size:14];

    registerButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Neo Sans Pro" size:14];
}

- (IBAction)openTwitterSignInViewController:(id)sender{
    TwitterSignInViewController *secondViewController = [[TwitterSignInViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TwitterSignInViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES]; 
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

At least i got the console output by enabling Zombie Objects.
Here is the output. But i couldn't find the error yet

```
2012-08-01 21:11:30.569 adMingle[3156:f803] *** -[LoginViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6857420
```

Comment: Can you copy the full message from the console? And how is this view controller being presented?

Comment: Please show us the console log so we can help you.

Comment: @FirozeLafeer what you mean with "how is this view controller being presented?"

Comment: I'm assuming `openTwitterSignInViewController:` is implemented in some view controller? How is that view controller being presented on the screen? (I suspect you're not keeping a strong reference to that view controller). If this method is not implemented in a view controller, then you might tell us more about which object in your app is supposed to be receiving this `openTwitterSignInViewController:` message.

Comment: @FirozeLafeer yes openTwitterSignInViewController is implemented in a view controller that name LoginViewController. LoginViewController is pushed by main view controller with code below UIViewController *secondViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];  at viewDidLoad method. All of these View Controllers has only view, there is no Window object. Also main view controller has Navigation Controller.

Comment: ok, you probably meant to use `viewDidAppear:` there, not `viewDidLoad`. But I don't think that's the issue here.

Comment: If you go to Xcode's Breakpoint navigator and set an exception breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions ('+' sign at the bottom), it may give you better information or at least stop at the **real** error instead of that line in main.m.

Comment: @FirozeLafeer no wiewDidLoad, i added whole of LoginViewController.m You can check it.

Comment: @PhillipMills nothing chaged, still i can see exception at main.m file.

Comment: @FirozeLafeer i found the console message, could you help now?

Comment: Yes, now can we see the code that actually presents the LoginViewController? Maybe also a screenshot of the connection to the button. BTW, I meant you *shouldn't* be using viewDidLoad to present this, not that you didn't. But that's a different issue I think.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an IBAction in .m file also.The method name should be same everywhere:

```
-(IBAction)openTwitterSignInViewController:(id)sender;
```

Comment: i had changed. at my first try i got unrecognized selector error; at second try nothing happend at my last try i got same error with above.

Comment: I connected with Touch Down event. I think yes, because i can see circle with dot inside at .m file near the name of method.

Comment: `IBAction` is just a preprocessor macro that means `void`.  It's used as a flag for Interface Builder, there's no practical difference between the two that would matter here.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7374691/423699). I had added a property to main view controller and allocate then call `pushViewController`

Answer (score 0):

Can u post the code in the viewcontroller from where you are showing this LoginViewController ? This issue is because, from somewhere your object is being over released.